# cannot import name 'Cursor' or 'Character'

Tags: python, class, import

I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't import any of the other classes after the Document class. I'm try to run the code in the python console, but I keep getting import errors like this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Character'
```

Here is the code:

```
class Document:
    def __init__(self):
        self.characters = []
        self.cursor = Cursor(self)
        self.filename = ''

    def insert(self, character):
        if not hasattr(character, 'character'):
            character = Character(character)
        self.characters.insert(self.cursor.position, character)
        self.cursor += 1

    def delete(self):
        del self.characters[self.cursor.position]

    def save(self):
        f = open(self.filename, 'w')
        f.write(''.join(self.characters))
        f.close()

class Cursor:
    def __init__(self, document):
        self.document = document
        self.position = 0

    def forward(self):
        self.position += 1

    def back(self):
        self.position -= 1

    def home(self):
        while self.document.characters[self.position-1] != '\n':
            self.position -= 1
            if self.position == 0:
                # Got to beginning of file before newline
            break

class Character:
    def __init__(self, character, bold=False, italic=False,
             underline=False):
        assert len(character) == 1
        self.character = character
        self.bold = bold
        self.italic = italic
        self.underline = underline
```

Comment: what exactly are you typing in the python console and what is your directory structure? where does this code live?

Comment: So when I type in "from document import Document", this will work. But when I do " from document import Cursor" or "from document import Character", I get the import errors.

Comment: Directory structure is:
Documents
-Python
--OOP
---Chapter5
----document.py

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your results with this code; everything can be imported without errors. Also, the `break` needs to be indented in the Cursor class

Comment: Thanks I wasn't having issues with the break, it just indented weird when I posted it here.

Comment: You shouldn't need to import `Character` if  you are working on the same script.

Comment: You may be importing the wrong file. Try `import document; print(document.__file__)` and see if the file path points to the file you wanted to import.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation error:

```
    if self.position == 0:
        # Got to beginning of file before newline
        # the following line was not indented deeply enough
        break
```

Comment: I wasn't having issues with the break, it just indented weird when I posted it here.

Comment: Then I'll have to agree with other comments here and suggest that I cannot reproduce your error. The interpreter only complained about your _unintended_ indentation error.